# How to add cookie on click in java script

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

How to add cookie on click in java script? On click I am calling linkedin authentication page..once authenticated I want to return back to the page where I called authentication. I want to store continue url in cookie and pass it..can anyone suggest?

Comment: The page you want to set the cookie on is on the same domain as the one reading it?

Comment: yes Paul. The same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to track which pages a user logs in from, I'd suggest using [*sessionStorage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) instead of a *Cookie*. *sessionStorage* has the added benifit of clearing when the browser is closed, so it is less likely you'll get items left over from previous times you were on the website. To navigate or get the current URL, use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).

Say you have your log in link

```
<a id="foo" href="some_link_that_sends_you_to_login">click</a>
```

Then you could add an event listener to it such as

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem('last_seen_url', window.location.href);
    }
);
```

Next, on your return page you can get this information back with

```
var goToURL = sessionStorage.getItem('last_seen_url') || '/';
sessionStorage.removeItem('last_seen_url'); // always clean up after yourself
window.location.href = goToURL;
```

It would be similar with cookies, using the [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), but *JavaScript* does not provide a good native interface for this. You'll need to implement something yourself, such as the example on *MDN*. Remember that all cookie data gets sent to the server with every page request, so you'll be generating more overhead for each thing stored as a cookie.